# MonoTouch Play System Sound

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, audiotoolbox, system-sounds

I would like to play a beep sound, when my alert dialog appears. How do I play the sound when a push notification appears? The code I need is similar to these links:

http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/23/snippet-playing-a-system-sound/

I cannot find this API anywhere:

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MonoTouch this function is named `MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.SystemSound.PlaySystemSound`.

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9905008/220643) on how to play a sound from a file.