# Play default iOS system sound with Monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, audiotoolbox

I want to play the keyboard 'click' sound when pressing buttons in my app.
How do I access this sound clip with Monotouch? I don't want to pass my own sound using AudioToolbox SystemSound.FromFile(). So far all my searches have led to this solution or Objective-C code using 'AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID' which I'm having trouble translating to C#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831671/playing-system-sound-without-importing-your-own

Comment: I'm looking for a C# example to work with

Comment: The API's are 1:1. The only difference will be syntactical, I promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With iOS 7.0 and higher, Stephane Delcroix answer seems not to work anymore...

But you can easily find the path to all the sounds in this nice project:
https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary

Here is the code I used und iOS 7 (take care, it might not work with the simulator!)

```
    private const string NotificationSoundPath = @"/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/Fanfare.caf";

    public static void TriggerSoundAndViber()
    {
        SystemSound notificationSound = SystemSound.FromFile(NotificationSoundPath);
        notificationSound.AddSystemSoundCompletion(SystemSound.Vibrate.PlaySystemSound);
        notificationSound.PlaySystemSound();
    }
```

Also the using() construct in the answer above caused trouble  in my case... it seems like it released the sound too early, I only can hear it (and even then not complete with viber) with a breakpoint on PlaySystemSound().

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's not a 1:1 port from the code in [Playing system sound without importing your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831671/playing-system-sound-without-importing-your-own), but this should do the work:

```cs
var path = NSBundle.FromIdentifier ("com.Apple.UIKit").PathForResource ("Tock", "aiff");
using (var systemSound = new SystemSound (NSUrl.FromFilename (path))) {
    systemSound.PlaySystemSound ();
}
```

`SystemSound` is defined in `MonoTouch.AudioToolbox`. Make sure to also look at [MonoTouch Play System Sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428523/monotouch-play-system-sound) and [MonoTouch: Playing sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905008/monotouch-playing-sound)

Comment: Worked perfect for me, but had to use `"com.apple.UIKit"` instead of `"com.Apple.UIKit"`