# Sound not playing on iOS device but working in iOS simulators

Tags: ios, monogame

Using the latest Monogame source 06/03/13 from GitHub, my game is playing sound effects just fine when run in the ipad/iPhone simulators (in OSX on VMWare), but when i deploy/debug it to an iPad 4 there is no sound at all. In the application output window, occasionally i see Failed to get buffer attributes: when performing an ingame action that should play a sound. As sound plays in the simulators i'm assuming i've compiled the xnbs correctly using the monogame sound processor. fwiw I compiled these using a visual studio 2012 Windows Phone Game library project. And heres how im playing my intro sound when the game loads.

```
public override void Activate(bool instancePreserved)
    {
        if (!instancePreserved)
        {
            if (content == null) 
                content = new ContentManager(ScreenManager.Game.Services, "Content");

            backgroundTexture = content.Load<Texture2D>(MyGame.Settings.Assets.SplashBackground);
            introSound = content.Load<SoundEffect>(MyGame.Settings.Assets.IntroSound);
        }
        introSound.CreateInstance().Play();
    }
```

Anyone know what would cause this and how to fix it?

Comment: is the file .wav format?

Comment: yes, it is before it is converted to xnb by the content pipeline. I know little of what is in an xnb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else scratching there head over this I solved it by configuring the AudioSession by doing this as suggested in a comment from  miguel.de.icaza [Sound not working in iOS for iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963098/sound-not-working-in-ios-for-ipad?rq=1)

```
MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.AudioSession.Initialize();   
MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.AudioSession.Category = MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.AudioSessionCategory.MediaPlayback;   
MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.AudioSession.SetActive(true);
```

I don't know the reason why the Simulator would play and a real device wouldn't, or why this isnt taking care of by monogame.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an MP3 either directly or via the Content pipeline.